# How to display array data with jquery.each()

Tags: jquery

Following array data I have generated with mysql_fetch_array() using PHP.

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array 
       ( 
        [0] => 4 
        [msg_id] => 4 
        [1] => 1 
        [uid_fk] => 1 
        [2] => dddddddddddddd88234234 
        [message] => dddddddddddddd88234234 
       ) 
       [1] => Array 
       ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [msg_id] => 3 
        [1] => 1 
        [uid_fk] => 1 
        [2] => 2324234 
        [message] => 2324234 
       )
       [2] => Array 
       (
         [0] => 2 
         [msg_id] => 2 
         [1] => 1 
         [uid_fk] => 1 
         [2] => 123123 
         [message] => 123123 
         )
     )
```

Comment: Why in the world do you want to use jquery for displaying your php array?

Comment: Atleat mention what you are intending to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)*(PHP)* your array, then use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)*(jQuery)*.

Comment: I've made a jsFiddle example here with your array converted into JSON : [http://jsfiddle.net/2NRKJ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/2NRKJ/1/)